# Fill a grid with values obtained from the form?? EXTJS

Tags: php, extjs, grid

i have a form, and i need to fill an a grid with the fields values.

In this moment, the combobox values are obtained through a SQL query in a PHP file that are called by JSON Store to fill the form.

The same way i using to fill the grid data but with other store for grid only.

Actually i fill the grid by JSON method.

That is my JSON Store that call some values that are filled in the grid.

```
var store_grid_CC = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
//successProperty: 'success',
url: 'json/distribucion.php?opcion=grid',
autoLoad: true,
fields  : ['center_name', 'subcenter_id','subcenter_name', 'porc_distribucion'],
root    : 'grid',
});
```

and in the combobox listener i use this call to load the grid (because the grid should be filled when i select a value in the combo)

```
 store_grid_CC.load({
 params:{ subcenter_id: subcenter_id,
opcion:'grid'}
});
```

That Store go to distribucion.php and send the subcenter_id obtained from a combobox, and then the PHP file return by SQL query the center_name and subcenter_name that are filled in the first 2 columns of the grid (are 4).

But the last 2 columns should be filled with some data obtained from the textfields in the form.

Then my problem is that i have 2 way method to obtain data for this grid, (by JSON way, and value form way).

One solution that i think is get all data from the form fields, including the combobox values, but not calling to SQL and waiting a JSON response, otherwise, getting the RawValue from de combo field ( the final value, without use a subcenter_id).

Example: The combobox value is called with the:

```
form.getForm().findField('combobox').RawValue() that return a name.
```

and the textbox with:

```
form.getForm().findField('textfield').getValue() that return a number.
```

GRID:

```
     column1           column2        column3               column4
```

---

row1   comboRawValue    comboRawValue    texfieldgetValue   texfieldgetValue

---

row2       "car"            "truck"            20                   100

---

(is only example).

I need to put this data inside to the grid store and when i press a button like (Add row), this values should to inserted in the grid in a new row.

how can i do that?, othewise, ¿how can i to fill the Grid Store with data obtained from the form?.

i trying with SimpleStores, JSONStores, but i dont know how to give the form values to store to be readed by grid after. I have not been successful.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: You want to use the same names for your form fields that you use for your grid columns and store fields.**

E.g. Form fields:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Test string',
    name: 'Test1'
},{
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    fieldLabel: 'Test bool',
    name: 'Test2'
},{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Test number',
    name: 'Test3'
}]
```

E.g. model fields:

```
Ext.define('MyModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:[{
        name: 'Test1',
        type: 'string'
    },{
        name: 'Test2',
        type: 'bool'
    },{
        name: 'Test3',
        type: 'int'
    }]
});
```

E.g. Grid columns:

```
columns:[{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    text: 'Test string',
    dataIndex: 'Test1'
},{
    xtype:'checkcolumn',
    text: 'Test bool',
    dataIndex: 'Test2'
},{
    xtype: 'numbercolumn',
    text: 'Test number',
    dataIndex: 'Test3'
}]
```

**Step 2: Bind a record to the form.**

When creating a new entry, create a new model instance and bind it to the form:

```
form.setRecord(Ext.create('MyModel'))
```

When saving, update the record and add it to the store if it isn't already.

```
form.updateRecord();
if(store.indexOf(form.getRecord()==-1) store.add(form.getRecord());
```

When editing an existing entry, bind the record to the store, for instance the fifth record:

```
form.setRecord(store.getAt(4));
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander !, Thats works with EXTJS 4? I made this question because i not working with models files (like extjs6), only i working with Simple and JSON Stores, and i recently learning EXTJS .

Comment: Well, in ExtJS 4, models are even required, while in ExtJS6 most stores can work without a model.